# Writing to file in python

Tags: python, file

I wrote such a code that should write all files in the directory to a text file, but when the code is executed, nothing appears in the file and does not give errors:

```py
import glob, os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test")
for file in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
    file = open('files.txt', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8')
    file.write(str(file))
    file.close()
```

Comment: Try open the file before the for loop, and make sure file.write is indented within the for loop. Can you confirm this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name file as variable for 2 different purposes at the same time. to open your file and to read in your file names.
Just change the name of your file like this to out_file...

```
for file in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
    
    out_file = open('files.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    out_file.write(str(file))

out_file.close()
```

Comment: It didn't help, sorry

Comment: The code itself is executed, but there is no result

Comment: Is the file created?

Comment: sure, files.txt

Comment: if you put a print statement just inside the loop "print(file)" , is there anything being printed?

Comment: If not, there is something wrong with your path or there are no mp4 files in your path

Comment: oh, sorry, I thought that all files in the directory should be written to the folder with the script itself, but right now I tried to create the files.txt file in the folder with mp4 files and everything works fine there. thank you!